# nestjs / TypeOrm database transaction

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Assuming we have 2 services, A and B.
Service A has a function doing the following:

1. Validate the data
2. Call a service B function, that makes changes to the database
3. Do some more stuff
4. Do changes to the database

Now, let's assume that one of the following, steps 3 or 4 failed.
Since service B made changes in the database, those changes are still there.

Is there any way of rolling the database back in this case? I though about database transactions, but I couldn't find any way to do that in nest js, although it is supported by TypeOrm, it doesn't look natural to nest.
If not, I am now "stuck" with the changes occured by service B, but without the changes should have happen by A.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many solutions are available, they should all be based on SQL transaction management.

Personally I feel that the simplest way to achieve that is to use the same `EntityManager` instance when you execute code on your database. Then you can use something like:

```
getConnection().transaction(entityManager -> {
    service1.doStuff1(entityManager);
    service2.doStuff2(entityManager);
});
```

You can spawn a `QueryRunner` from an `EntityManager` instance that will be wrapped in the same transaction in case you execute raw SQL outside ORM operations. You need also to spawn `Repository` instances from `EntityManager` as well or they will execute code outside the main transaction.

Comment: While this is a solution, there's an obvious issue: Every service method will have to accept an EntityManager parameter.  And if those services use other injectables, like data-access objects (DAOs), then the service methods will need to pass the EntityManager instance down the chain even further (e.g. to DAO methods).  I think this is an obvious and impulsive solution--a solution that works!--but it adds significant boilerplate code and doesn't fit well with DI and IoC.

Comment: @avejidah you don't have ThreadLocal in TypeScript Node so you cannot store a context instance where you keep reference of the entity manager along all the services. Singleton won't work either as you have an entity manager per request (many ones are processed together in node thanks to event queue). The only way to keep an entity manager everywhere would be to store it in some way in the execution context of NestJS but you would loose manual entity manager usage and manual transaction management which can be needed.

Comment: I personally keep the parameter and use a decorator along the method to inject a new entity manager if it is null so I never have to worry about initializing it. Keeping explicit transaction management is more important to me than code sugar, I don't find it boilerplate personally.

Comment: @zenbeni could you share a code snippet? which decorator are you using? maybe `@TransactionManager`?

Comment: Any suggestions if I use [nestjsx/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud)

Answer (score 13):

[typeorm-transactional](https://github.com/Aliheym/typeorm-transactional) uses CLS (Continuation Local Storage) to handle and propagate transactions between different repositories and service methods.

```js
@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  constructor(
    private readonly authorRepository: AuthorRepository,
    private readonly postRepository: PostRepository,
  ) {}

  @Transactional() // will open a transaction if one doesn't already exist
  async createPost(authorUsername: string, message: string): Promise<Post> {
    const author = await this.authorRepository.create({ username: authorUsername });
    return this.postRepository.save({ message, author_id: author.id });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: This, IMO, is the most succinct approach

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I solved it since I needed to use a pessimistic lock.

I feel it is the "Nest" way of doing things as you can simply ask `NestJS` to inject an instance of a Typeorm `Connection` and you're good to go.

```js
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  // 1. Inject the Typeorm Connection
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private connection: Connection) { }

  async findById(id: number): Promise<Thing> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // 2. Do your business logic
      this.connection.transaction(async entityManager => {
        resolve(
          await entityManager.findOne(Thing, id, {
            lock: { mode: 'pessimistic_write' },
          }),
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Simply place whatever other logic you need inside the `.transaction` block and you're good to go.

**NOTE:** You MUST use the `entityManager` provided by the `.transaction` method or else it will not work.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew how to inject the connection

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you have to use the same transaction manager for both database operations. Unfortunately, I do not have an example repository, but I have found a potential solution using Continuation Local Storage (CLS) in Node:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1895

This applies to Express.js, but you can create an instance of TransactionManager (for example, in a nest middleware) and store it per each request context. You then will be able to re-use this transactional manager across your service method calls, provided they are annotated with the @Transaction decorator implementation in the link above.

If there are no errors in your function chain, the transaction manager will commit all the changes made. Otherwise, the manager will roll back any changes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
function assignChildToParent(nestedObj, parentIdKey) {
  const parentMap = {};

  for (const prop in nestedObj) {
    if (nestedObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      const obj = nestedObj[prop];
      const parentId = obj[parentIdKey];

      parentMap[prop] = { ...obj, children: {} };

      if (parentId !== null && parentMap.hasOwnProperty(parentId)) {
        parentMap[parentId].children[prop] = parentMap[prop];
      }
    }
  }

  const result = {};

  for (const prop in parentMap) {
    if (parentMap.hasOwnProperty(prop) && parentMap[prop][parentIdKey] === null) {
      result[prop] = parentMap[prop];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const nestedObj = {
  obj1: { name: 'Parent 1', parentId: null },
  obj2: { name: 'Parent 2', parentId: 'obj1' },
  obj3: { name: 'Parent 3', parentId: null }
};

const parentIdKey = 'parentId';

const result = assignChildToParent(nestedObj, parentIdKey);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).